# Angular E2E scenario selector does not detect if hyperlink is visible

Tags: angularjs, angular-scenario

I have the following e2e test:

```
expect(element('a[name="prevStepButton"]:visible').count()).toEqual(1);
```

On the following template:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" name="prevStepButton" ng-show="wizardstep > 1" 
 ng-click="prevStep()">Previous</a>
```

Where `$scope.wizardstep = 2`

Unfortunately the expectation is always 0.

Anyone any idea what is wrong with this code/test?

Comment: Seems to occur only in IE. Something we need to work around or can we make fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `browser().navigateTo('/');` before your expect?